# CSS Grid content not wrapping correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, css-grid

I've created a grid with grid items that output custom fields in from a WordPress theme, for example, Title, Subtitle, and Excerpt.

When I had some holding-place text in the grid with a p tag the text was wrapping correctly.

However, now that the dummy content is replaced with a  function, the text is a single string which does not wrap to the grid div.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MBas.png)

I've been looking for solutions but haven't been able to crack it - any suggestions would be hugely helpful.

Code here:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid-item">
     <div class="grid-header">
         <div class="grid-header-text">
             <h3 class="grid-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
             <h4 class="grid-subtitle"><?php the_field('grid_subtitle'); ?> </h4>
         </div>

         <div class="grid-header-icon"> 
             <i class="fas fa-angle-double-up fa-3x"></i> 
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="grid-body">     
         <p class="content">
             <?php the_field('grid_excerpt'); ?>
         </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.feature-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}


.grid-item {
    border: solid black 1px;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 9px;

}

.grid-header {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 100px;

}

.grid-body {}
```

the parent item as requested by one user:

```
<div class="section grid-section">

    <div class="feature-grid">

    <?php $frontPageGrid = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'grid-item',
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'order' => 'ASC'
```

));

while($frontPageGrid->have_posts()) {
    $frontPageGrid->the_post(); ?>

```
        <div class="grid-item">

            <div class="grid-header">

                <div class="grid-header-text">

                    <h3 class="grid-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <h4 class="grid-subtitle"><?php the_field('grid_subtitle'); ?> </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-header-icon"> <i class="fas fa-angle-double-up fa-3x"></i> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-body">

            <p class="content">
            <?php the_field('grid_excerpt'); ?>
            </p>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you kindly put the rendered HTML including the parent of "grid-item" for a better understanding? A code snippet would help much better.

Comment: Thanks Niraj, I've tried to add this

Comment: Created a snippet on https://jsfiddle.net/svq6cLzx/ It works fine. Can you provide the same kind of example of your "not working code" ?

Comment: Thanks Niraj - it also works fine for me with placeholder text. What I'm having problems with is when I call a Wordpress function to display content related to a custom post i've created - for example the_extract(); or the_content(); the text runs outside of the div.

This also happens on another page I've created, so I might be missing something fundamental with how wordpress functions are working here.

Comment: If you can share a link, it would be more helpful.